# Output shows un common characters while changing from infix to postfix notation using C++

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, postfix-notation, infix-notation

```
Input:
3
(a+(b*c))
((a+b)*(z+x))
((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))

Output:
abc*+
ab+zx+*
at+bac++cd+^*
```

There are brackets in all the inputs, so precedence order of operators need not be checked.
The following is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  unsigned short t;
  int len ,top = -1, i;
  char str[400], newStr[400], stack[400];
  char* p_newStr = newStr;
  scanf("%hu", &t);
  while (t--)
  {
    if (scanf("%s", str) <= 400)
    {
      len = strlen(str);
      i = 0;
      while(i < len)
      {
        if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122)
        {
          p_newStr = p_newStr + str[i];
        }
        else if (str[i] == '(' || str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '^')
        {
          top++;
          stack[top] = str[i];
        }
        else if (str[i] == ')')
        {
          while(stack[top] != '(')
          {
            p_newStr = p_newStr + stack[top];
            top--;
          }
          top--; //the '(' is discarded from the stack.
        }
        i++;
      }
      printf ("%s\n", newStr);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I do not have much experience with handling strings in C or C++ using character arrays or library classes. 
When I run it, I get un recognizable symbols instead of the correct postfix notation.

Comment: what are the uncommon characters? it is either junk by not an initialized variable or trying to print as ascii a non ascii number

Comment: c strings, strxxx(), printf()... Is the C++ tag really justified ?

Comment: @jgr208 I mean it is printing characters not recognized by my terminal's character set. If it is in ASCII, my terminal should recognize.

Comment: no they are outside of the ascii range i forget what the range of ascii so lets say you are trying to print out 700 as an ascii letter it will be like what this isnt related to any character but hey ok ill try and print out junk since it doesnt know how to handle it

Comment: @jgr208: I think ascii range is from 0 to 255? Since it is 7 bits.

Comment: @aste123 Sorry, that isn't a duplicate of that question I've marked. Though your question is a bit poor.

Comment: yes it is. so if you try to print out 256 as a character it will give you junk

Comment: @jgr208 ok, I will try print individual characters as %d and see.

Comment: @jgr208 I get 16, -58 and 108 for the first 3 characters when input is `1 (a+(b*c))`. Is there any problem with the way I'm handling the strings? Storage and manipulation?

Comment: -58 isnt in the ascii range

Comment: also maybe the b*c should be first converted to ascii before multiplied unless you are concatenating.

Comment: @jgr208 The numbers seem to change with multiple runs, maybe I am accessing wrong index while storing or printing.

Comment: @jgr208 yes I'm concatenating to form the postfix notation or expression.

Comment: @jgr208 all numbers.

Comment: hmmm and each time you give it abc which is 95,96,97?

Comment: `p_newStr = p_newStr + str[i](or stack[top]);` ?? this is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The operators are in the stack array so when closing bracket is encountered in the `str`, I should pop the stack element and add to the newStr is my logic. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Christophe The code is using c++ style comments. Must be the reason. :P

Comment: @TimSeguine what? c and c++ comments are the same just the includes are different...

Comment: and `printf ("%s\n", newStr);` `newStr` never assigned.

Comment: @jgr208 Single line comments (i.e. using `//`) are also known as C++ style comments. Because before C99 these weren't valid in C.

Comment: @TimSeguine ahh gotcha, never heard that term before but yes it is a real thing. learn something new every day i guess

Comment: @jgr208 to be perfectly clear though, I was being glib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you process `p_newStr` without initializint it, and only performing pointer arithmetic on it.  I guess, that you wanted to see it as a string, adding chars to it.

So first initialisze it:

```
    char* p_newStr = newStr; // It was unitinitalised, pointing at random location
```

Then note that `p_newStr = p_newStr + str[i]`  means adding the value of the char str[i], converted to int, to the pointer p_newStr.  That's pointer arithmetic.  Replace this statement with:

```
    *p_newStr++ = str[i];   // instead of p_newStr = ...
```

and there is another one taking a char from the stack[]:

```
    *p_newStr++ = stack[top];   // instead of p_newStr = ...
```

Finally, put an ending null terminator to the c string you've built, just before your printf():

```
    *p_newStr++ = 0;
```

Once these corrections made, the code produces exactly the expected results.

Comment: since newStr was created with `char newStr[400]`. Can I just use `newStr` as the pointer to the string instead of the `p_newStr`?

Comment: no, because `newStr[]` is an array.  Writing `newstr` just converts it to a pointer.  If you're not familiar with pointers you could however use newstr[j] where j is an index starting at 0 and incremented after you add a new char

Comment: What is the difference between `newStr` and `p_newStr`. Since newStr[] is an array, newStr should point to the address of newStr[0]. Is the not same as p_newStr? There is another problem with my solution. I need to handle more than one strings for example input is `3 (a+(b*c)) ((a+b)*(z+x)) ((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))`. In this case, the logic of my code still works but I need to be able to **reinitialize** the character arrays so that they can store new strings instead of appending the new characters after the already added NULL or 0 character. How do I do this?

Comment: p_newStr is just a pointer that could point anywhere. The simailarity of its name is not sufficient: you have to initialisz if explicitely. If you want to reinitialize, just reassign `p_newStr=newStr`:  the new chars you add will overwrite the old ones.  The ending 0 will cut the string in case the old string was longer.

Comment: Thank you! I get it. So that means we store address of `newStr[0]` in `p_newStr` and increment it as required. We cannot increment `newStr` as it is like a constant pointing to `newStr[0]`. That also explains how the reinitialization works.

Answer (score 0):

```
p_newStr = p_newStr + str[i];
```

Should be:

```
*p_newStr++ = str[i];
```

The way you currently have it, you are never actually modifying the new string.  You make this mistake in two places.